# How can I use an align environment flush left?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment, amsmath, align

Is there a way possible to imitate the `align` environment for math mode commands, without having all writing being placed toward the center on the output page?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 &= \cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2) \\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2 &= \sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It's not clear by what you mean by *without having everything being centered* on the output page. For one, it is the `gather` and `gather*` environments rather than the `align` and `align*` environments which center their output on a line.

Comment: is there a reason you are adding spaces `\;` around the equal signs?  this wide spacing is reminiscent of what is produced by `\eqalign`, and it's not considered good style in mathematics publications.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The amsmath package has a `fleqn` option which, according to the manual (`texdoc amsmath`) has the following effect:

> Position equations at a fixed indent from the left margin rather than centered in the text column.

Thus:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}
```

seems to be what you are after.

The `mathtools` package loads `amsmath` internally and passes any unknown arguments on to it.  This includes the `fleqn` option.  Thus:

```
\usepackage[fleqn]{mathtools}
```

also works.

Here's a comparison of the outputs.  The upper one is without `fleqn` and the lower one with.

[image: fleqn option]

Comment: Andrew, Thanks. So is there an option for this as well using the `mathtools` package or is it already built in somehow?

Comment: @night owl: I didn't realise you were using `mathtools`.  As that loads `amsmath` it's easy to adapt my answer to that case.  I've updated my answer.

Comment: @AndrewStacey I just tried this, but my equations do not get flushed *entirely* to the left (there is still some margin on the left hand side). What could I try to remove this remaining margin?

Comment: @texfan: You can use `\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}` under the `fleqn` command.

Answer (score 77):

As Andrew mentions you can use `\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}`, but this will mean tha **all** you equations will be moved to the left.

However, if you want to be able to have some centered and some on the left, then you can use the `flalign` environment.  But, note the trailing `&` that is required when this is used.  As mentioned by egreg, the trailing `&` in the `flalign` environment is only required in one of the lines.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}% mathtools includes this so this is optional
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}% centered
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 &= \cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2) \\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2 &= \sin(\theta_1+\theta_2)
\end{align*}

\begin{flalign*}% left aligned
\cos\theta_1 \cos\theta_2-\sin\theta_1\sin\theta_2 &= \cos(\theta_1 +\theta_2) &\\
\sin\theta_1 \cos\theta_2 + \cos\theta_1 \sin\theta_2 &= \sin(\theta_1+\theta_2) &% Need tailing alignment char to get all the way left
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

I removed the `\;` from the OP's MWE, which inserted additional spacing where it was not necessary.

Comment: One can add, say, `\qquad` in front of the first line in order not to get left flushing; the trailing `&` is needed only in one of the lines. Note that those `\;` commands are wrong.

Comment: Nice to know about that.  (To produce the picture in my (updated) answer, I introduced a `\fleqn` hack that reset stuff according to the `fleqn` option.  If I'd known about `falign` ...)

Comment: @egreg: Totally agree. I noticed those, but since it appeared that `\;` were intentionally added, it was the OPs style of choice to have additional space.

Comment: @Andrew: Wow!! Can't believe that I was actually able to teach you something..

Comment: egreg, Peter: So how should one do correct spacing for something as so? I'm open to new ways.

Comment: Just remove the `\;` and you'll get the "correct" spacing. It is preferable to let TeX determine the spacing so that it is consistent.  I have removed them form this answer in case others see this and think that they should be there.

Comment: Peter: Is there an option analogous to the left align for right align, for e.g. `fralign`?

Comment: Best to post a separate question as someone in the future may benefit from it...

Comment: Does this work with the beamer class? (I ask because after a quick attempt it did not seem to, at least not with the typical packages I use). Oh wait, this weird combo of ``&`` and ``&&`` worked: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/364332/flalign-doesnt-work-in-beamer

Answer (score 17):

I'm not sure what you mean by "immitate", but I guess you mean you don't want the equations centered, but aligned in another way. A [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would have been nice, to better understand your problem, to know what documentclass you are using, etc.
Anyway, you can have equations aligned differently with align, if you load the `amsmath` package and write something like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}
\begin{document}
\noindent Blah
\begin{align*}
y = ad + da\\
y = ad + da
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

As you probably guessed, `\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}` lets you control the indentation.

Comment: Very useful comment. I was perplexed by the indentation that was still present in my text.