# Equations in the margin: automatic flush right or left?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, marginpar, double-sided

*How can I automatically have equations in a `\marginnote` aligned flush left or right in a two-sided document?*

A [previous question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28650/6903]) suggested to make equations flush left by using `flalign*` and extra alignment characters.  This can also be used to make the equations flush right as demonstrated below.  The question: how to do this automatically for equations that appear in `\marginnote`s?  The solution probably will use an [if-then-else for even/odd pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/6143/6903), but how to cleanly incorporate this with the `(fl)align*` environment?

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Is flush left (manually)
  \begin{flalign*}
    a&=1 &\\
    b&=1 &
  \end{flalign*}}
\lipsum[2]
\marginnote{How to make flush left automatically?
  \begin{align*}
    a&=1\\
    b&=1
  \end{align*}}
\lipsum[3-6]
\marginnote{Is flush right (manually):
  \begin{flalign*}
    && a&=1\\
    && b&=1
  \end{flalign*}}
\lipsum[7]
\marginnote{How to make flush right automatically?
  \begin{align*}
    a&=1\\
    b&=1
  \end{align*}}
\lipsum[8-9]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you do not need numbered equations, then use a simple `array`

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{marginnote}
\newenvironment{Array}
  {\arraycolsep=1.4pt\par$\array{rl}}
  {\endarray$}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Is flush left (manually)
  \begin{Array}
    a&=1 \\
    b&=1 
  \end{Array}}
\lipsum[2]
\marginnote{How to make flush left automatically?
  \begin{Array}
    a&=1\\
    b&=1
  \end{Array}}
\lipsum[3-6]
\marginnote{Is flush right (manually):
  \begin{Array}
    a&=1\\
    b&=1
  \end{Array}}
\lipsum[7]
\marginnote{How to make flush right automatically?
  \begin{Array}
    a&=1\\
    b&=1
  \end{Array}}
\lipsum[8-9]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I think this is going to do it.  It would still be nice to be able to use some of the alignment capabilities of `align` etc. but that will spoil the nice margin alignment anyway, and there is not really space for several aligned columns with most margin notes.  I will play with it for a bit and then accept if it works as expected.  Thanks!

Comment: you can add an optional argument to `Align` for the column specification, then more columns are possible

Comment: @Herbert, thanks for the answer, but I am experiencing a problem with your solution. If my marginnote only contains an equation, there is a large skip / space inside of the marginnote, that pushes it down and does not appear at the right spot anymore. Is there a workaround to avoid this? I can just do `\vspace{-...}`, but that's quite a dirty hack.

Comment: use the inline math mode istead of a displayed one.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I would call semi-automatic.

The [`everyshi` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi) provides a hook into the page shipout routine by means of the `\EveryShipout` macro. As such, the code

```
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\def\flusheqnL{&} \def\flusheqnR{}%
\EveryShipout{%
  \ifodd\value{page}
    \gdef\flusheqnL{} \gdef\flusheqnR{&&}%
  \else
    \gdef\flusheqnL{&} \gdef\flusheqnR{}%
  \fi
}%
```

defines `\flusheqnL` and `\flusheqnR` to have default values of `&` and `{}`, respectively, and alters these values based on the page number `\value{page}` at shipout. If the page number is odd, the values are swapped to `{}` and `&&`, respectively, to accommodate a different alignment on the following (even) page. In fact, these macros are used as hooks for alignment characters in the `flalign*` environment. However, this requires you to typeset your `marginnote` equations using the following format:

```
\marginnote{...
  \begin{flalign*}
    \flusheqnR ...&... \flusheqnL \\
    \flusheqnR ...&... \flusheqnL
  \end{flalign*}}
```

Here's an example of the output:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\usepackage{marginnote}% http://ctan.org/pkg/marginnote
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\def\flusheqnL{&} \def\flusheqnR{}%
\EveryShipout{%
  \ifodd\value{page}
    \gdef\flusheqnL{} \gdef\flusheqnR{&&}%
  \else
    \gdef\flusheqnL{&} \gdef\flusheqnR{}%
  \fi
}%

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1]
\marginnote{Is flush left (manually)
  \begin{flalign*}
    a&=1 &\\
    b&=1 &
  \end{flalign*}}
\lipsum[2]
\marginnote{How to make flush left automatically?
  \begin{flalign*}
    \flusheqnR a&=1 \flusheqnL \\
    \flusheqnR b&=1 \flusheqnL
  \end{flalign*}}
\lipsum[3-6]
\marginnote{Is flush right (manually):
  \begin{flalign*}
    && a&=1\\
    && b&=1
  \end{flalign*}}
\lipsum[7]
\marginnote{How to make flush right automatically?
  \begin{flalign*}
    \flusheqnR a&=1 \flusheqnL \\
    \flusheqnR b&=1 \flusheqnL
  \end{flalign*}}
\lipsum[8-9]
\end{document}
```

[image: Semi-automatic alignment of marginnote flalign*]

The redefinition of `\flusheqnL` and `\flusheqnR` has to be made global (via `\gdef`) in order for it to hold outside the group (within `\EveryShipout`).