# Left-align all equations in a block

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align

align environment without any explicit alignments points (given by &) right justifies the equations in the block. They can be left justified by putting & at the beginning of each equation. Is there any way to left justify them without starting &-s? Maybe some special environment or option? It seems to be an extra work to tell the compiler again and again that I want left alignment on each line.

Comment: See [How can I use an `align` environment flush left?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28650/5764)

Comment: That does not work. That left aligns the equation block. The equations within the block a still right aligned. I tried \usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath} and \begin{align*}
    1-3=2\    34343234234-98394895835=239283
\end{align*}

Comment: Close-voters: please notice that according to the comment, this is *not* a duplicate. **xivaxy** is not interested in using the `fleqn` option nor in having the equation block flushed left.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Left justification is the default (with `fleqn`) for the `gather`-environment. So simply use that, after all `align` is for aligning at user-specified points, which is not what you need.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
1-3=2 \\ 
34343234234-98394895835=239283
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: That works great! When it comes to left alignment, everyone usually mentions [fleqn], but does not say it should be in combination with gather.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand the question correctly, you can use an `array` with one column with left alignment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{array}{@{}l@{}} 
1-3=2 \\ 
34343234234-98394895835=239283 
\end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to have *all* your equations to be flush left, pass the `[fleqn]` option to `amsmath`, thereby pushing content to the left. Then patch `\align@preamble` in the following way:

```
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\align@preamble}{\hfil}{}{}{}
\makeatother
```

This removes the right-flushing `\hfil` from the preamble.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,etoolbox}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{amsmath,etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\align@preamble}{\hfil}{}{}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\begin{align}
  1-3=2 \\ 
  34343234234-98394895835=239283 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

If you wish to have the content all the way flush with the left margin, add

```
\setlength{\mathindent}{0pt}
```

to your preamble as well.