# How to align a set of equations in the left yet retaining the auto-numbering?

Tags: equations, numbering, align

I have found many codes through which equations can be aligned in the left but the problem is it assigns either a single number to all the equations or no numbering at all. I want something like `fleqn` or `falign` that can retain the auto-numbering feature of `eqnarray`.

For example:

---

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
&A = B + C + .... \\ 
& A^\prime  = B^\prime + ...\\
&D  =  E + F ...\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

---

It assigns a single number to the whole set of equations, but I want numbering for individual equations and I don't want to assign numbers manually, it should be automated. Like when we use `eqnarray`.

Comment: the option `fleqn` for `amsmath` will position a *group* of equations with the leftmost edge of the widest member of the group at the left.  alignment within the group depends on the grouping structure specified, but every member of the group will be numbered individually.  if you will provide a compilable example showing a typical group that you would like to left-align, there is a possible approach that can be tried, but guessing what you want without an example isn't productive.  (oh -- welcome to tex.sx.)

Comment: Ok, I am editing the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I use an `align` environment flush left?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28650/5764)

Comment: It's not a duplicate.. because all of the existing threads don't have any numbering for the equations. Please don't close this thread.

Comment: the numbering is not affected by `[fleqn]` in any way you have used `aligned` inside `equation` which by design gives a single number for both centred and flush left. if you want each line numbered use `align` not `equation` that applies whether or not you use `fleqn`.

Comment: The question Werner linked to is using `align*` to stop numbers, just use the same forms without the `*` to get numbered equations.

Comment: now that you have shown what you want to do, and it has been pointed out that using `align` with no `*` will give that result, this question *is* a duplicate.  just a comment on your example -- don't put a `\\ ` after the last line; it will cause an extra equation number to be generated, but no equation to refer to.  you might want to have a look at the `amsmath` documentation (`texdoc amsmath`) where it explains the difference between `align` and `aligned`.

Comment: "align" doesn't align to the left ! Does it ?