# Equation Block alignment to the left

Tags: equations, align

i have three equations with number (reference) that i want to left align.

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran} 
\usepackage{cite} 
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, figurename=Figure, font=small]{caption} \usepackage[subrefformat=parens, labelformat=parens, font=small]{subfig} \usepackage{url} 
\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{hyperref} 
\usepackage{microtype} 
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct} 
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym} 
\usepackage[depth=subsubsection]{bookmark} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\usepackage{makecell} 
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{authblk} 
\usepackage{hhline} 
\usepackage{multirow} 
\usepackage{xparse} 
\usepackage{cleveref} 

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\frac{d}{dx}r^n=nx^{n-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
Length=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{[f't]^2+[g't]^2}dt
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

By default, the equations are center aligned. How can i make them left aligned? I already tried `\begin{flalign}...\end{flalign}`, `\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned} with [fleqn]` it did not work for me. Any help will be highly appretiated.

Comment: @bmv I already tried that, didn't work for me

Comment: please show small but complete document. we need to see used preamble (ONLY TO Math related packages). also let us know, if all equation should be left aligned or just this three.

Comment: @Zarko I am using no Math related packages, there was no need. And I need all equations left aligned. Equations are centered by default in LaTeX so I guess preamble doesn't has to do anything with equations being centered because its LaTeX default behavior.

Comment: if we not know, what you use, then we cant help you. please consider my previous comment. help us to help you!

Comment: @Zarko \documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, figurename=Figure, font=small]{caption} 
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens, labelformat=parens, font=small]{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage[depth=subsubsection]{bookmark}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cleveref}

Comment: @RajaAyaz, this you should add to your question ... this time i will do this for you.

Comment: @Zarko, this is my entire preamble. After this is immediately \begin{document}, is this of any help please?

Comment: Thank you for moving preamble to question @Zarko. I will remember to do so next time.

Comment: @RajaAyaz, not really. you ask me that i need to recreate your document from your code fragments ... and your question is not very clear. are all equation should be left aligned? are shoved equation follows one after another?

Comment: @Zarko, i cannot post a picture of the scenario otherwise i would have. The three equations are in three lines, each with an equation number. The equation numbers are all right aligned as they should, but the equations are not left aligned. they start somewhere in the middle of the line. i wanted them left-aligned.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How can I use an `align` environment flush left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28650/5764)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, but your question is not very clear, so the following solutions are based on pure guessing:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for generating dummy text, not use in real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
\begin{align}
            x   & = \frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}          \label{eq1} \\
\frac{d}{dx}r^n & = nx^{n-1}                                \label{eq2} \\
\mathrm{Length} & = \int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{[f't]^2+[g't]^2}dt    \label{eq3}
\end{align}
or
\begin{fleqn}
\begin{equation}\label{eq1}
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\frac{d}{dx}r^n=nx^{n-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
Length=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{[f't]^2+[g't]^2}dt
\end{equation}
\end{fleqn}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

which gives :

[image]

or in case that all equations in your document should be left aligned:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for generating dummy text, not use in real document

\begin{document}
\lipsum[11]
 \begin{equation}\label{eq1}
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq2}
\frac{d}{dx}r^n=nx^{n-1}
\end{equation}

\begin{equation}\label{eq3}
Length=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{[f't]^2+[g't]^2}dt
\end{equation}
or     
\begin{gather}
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}            \label{eq1} \\
\frac{d}{dx}r^n=nx^{n-1}                    \label{eq2} \\
Length=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{[f't]^2+[g't]^2}dt \label{eq3}
\end{gather}
\lipsum[11]

\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

**edit (1):**
If you will use a solution with `fleqn` environment, then you can set the indentation of equations by environment option (see [Bernard's][3] comment below). For example, for indentation of `2em`:

```
\begin{fleqn}[2em]    
\begin{gather}
x=\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}            \label{eq1} \\
\frac{d}{dx}r^n=nx^{n-1}                    \label{eq2} \\
Length=\int_{a}^{b}\sqrt{[f't]^2+[g't]^2}dt \label{eq3}
\end{gather}
\end{fleqn}
```

will move left border of equations for `2em` to right,

**edit (2):**
As [Barbara Beeton](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/579/barbara-beeton) pointed in her comment below, the use of `gather` environments has advantages over use of separated `equations`. You can compare results in the second example (observe spacing between equations). If a page or column break is needed, `amsmath` provides `\allowdisplaybreak` command.

For more information about use of `amsmath` packages see (new) [short math guide](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/short-math-guide).

Comment: Thank you very much @Zarko, that's exactly what I wanted. You solved the problem, highly appreciated, thanks dearie :)

Comment: Note the `fleqn`accepts an optional argument – the indentation of the group of equations from the left margin (`0pt` by default).

Comment: @Bernard, thank you for remind me on this.  however, i don't know which of provided solutions op will use. so i decided to not confuse him with this ...

Comment: @Zarko I used \begin{fleqn}...\end{fleqn} and it worked like a charm. Thanks again :)

Comment: @RajaAyaz, ok, than i will add Bernard comment to my answer.

Comment: might be worth mentioning that a multi-line environment (like `gather`) results in better/more consistent vertical spacing than separate equations.  if a page break is needed, `amsmath` provides `\allowdisplaybreak`.  (search for this command in answers to other questions, or to the `amsmath` users guide for details.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you for editing my answer. in answer are both examples, but i didn't emphasize by words the advantages of use `gather` environment. i will edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The `flalign` environment works, but you have to create  at least a second column with an `&`:

```
\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf, figurename=Figure, font=small]{caption}
\usepackage[subrefformat=parens, labelformat=parens, font=small]{subfig}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[dont-mess-around]{fnpct}
\usepackage[misc]{ifsym}
\usepackage[depth=subsubsection]{bookmark}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{nccmath}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[11]

  \begin{flalign}\label{eq1}
    & x =\frac{-b±\sqrt{b²-4ac}}{2a} & \\
    \label{eq2}
     & \frac{d}{dx}r^n =nx^{n-1} \\
     \label{eq6}
    & \text{Length} =∫_{a}^{b}√{[f't]²+[g't]²}\,dt
  \end{flalign}

Or even with the $ = $ signs aligned:

  \begin{flalign}\label{eqa1}
    x & =\frac{-b±\sqrt{b²-4ac}}{2a} & \\
    \label{eqa2}
    \frac{d}{dx}r^n & =nx^{n-1} \\
    \label{eqa6}
    \text{Length} & =∫_{a}^{b}√{[f't]²+[g't]²}\,dt
  \end{flalign}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for sparing time to help, yes your solution of flalign also worked. I liked the \usepackage{showframe}, i didn't know it and that was also something i needed. thanks :)

Comment: If you use the `geometry` package, there's also its `[showframe]` option.

Comment: I think it must be possible, though I have no precise idea at the moment. Anyway, you should post it as a new question.

Comment: Thanks @Bernard, I will post a new question regarding this.

Comment: @RajaAyaz: I've just found this [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31807/where-can-i-find-examples-of-decorated-borders-margins) to a similar question, which might be of interest to you.

Comment: Thank you very much, that looks interesting. I will definitely try that.