# flalign in algorithm

Tags: algorithms, algorithm2e, mathtools, flalign

This question is a bit related to the answer provided here:
[How can I use an align environment flush left?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/28650/how-can-i-use-an-align-environment-flush-left)

I use algorithm2e and mathtools to write an algorithm with an equation inside.
I want it to be on the left side. Why I have to add additional & (space after it added for clarity) at the beginning of a line when without algorithm environment I didn't have to?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}

\begin{document}

  \begin{algorithm}
    \begin{flalign*}
    &     \mu_\beta \leftarrow \frac{1}{m} \sum_{i=1}^{m}{x_1}&
    \end{flalign*}
  \end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TEX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/82917) Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}` instead of a code snippet. This makes our lives easier and increases the chance of people helping you.

Comment: Hi all :) I have added the changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with `algorithm2e` so I'll leave that out. Basically `align` and its siblings are in fact arrays of successive `rl` columns. `flalign` then stretches the intercolumn space *between these* `rl` *pairs* to fill the page width. This works of course only if you have at least two such pairs, meaning that you need at least two `&`: if you have only one `&` then you just jumped from the `r` to the `l` column, but you still have what `amsmath` calls "an equation column" (which as I said is realy a pair of columns), and this will be still centered.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[showframe,textwidth=8cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\begin{flalign*}
R & L &            R & L \\
right & left & right & left
\end{flalign*}
%
\begin{flalign*}
fooooo & \\
baz    &
\end{flalign*}
%
\begin{flalign*}
& fooooo \\
& baz
\end{flalign*}
%
\begin{flalign*}
& fooooo & \\
& baz    & 
\end{flalign*}
%
\begin{flalign*}
fooooo &&\\
baz    &&
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that in the last two examples it is in principle enough to put the second `&` in only one row, as that is enough to trigger the spreading mechanism.

Comment: That explains a lot! So does this means that math adds after first rl "an equation column" and other rl for stretching/centering and that I end up with 3 columns:rl, rl, and rl? So in the 1st example, the last column has 0 length (or still some- I experimented a bit and couldn't find a difference?)

Comment: @Wilk I don't really understand the first part of your comment. In the first example there are four columns `rlrl`, and the stretching is between the first pair `rl` and the second one.

Comment: I thought, that by standard align environment have r and l column, and You have written that amsmath adds "an equation column" (l+r), so to make centering one would need other columns- maybe I misunderstood